# Sharing dictionary over multiprocesses (TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref' object)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I want to create a class `Storage` where each object has a dictionary `orderbooks` as a property.
I want to write on `orderbooks` from the main process by invoking the method `write`, but I want to defer this action to another process and ensuring that the dictionary `orderbooks` is accessible from the main process.

To do so, I create a `Mananger()` that I pass during the definition of the object and that is used to notify the processes about the changes of the dictionary. My code is the following:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

class Storage():
    def __init__(self,manager):
        self.manager = manager
        self.orderbooks = self.manager.dict()

    def store_value(self,el):
        self.orderbooks[el[0]] = el[1]

    def write(self,el:list):
        p = Process(target=self.store_value,args=(el,))
        p.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    manager=Manager()
    book1 = Storage(manager)
    book1.write([0,1])
```

However, when I run this code, I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/main_user/PycharmProjects/handle_queue/main.py", line 21, in <module>
    book1.write([0,1])
  File "/Users/main_user/PycharmProjects/handle_queue/main.py", line 13, in write
    p.start()
  File "/Users/main_user/opt/anaconda3/envs/handle_queue/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/Users/main_user/opt/anaconda3/envs/handle_queue/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "/Users/main_user/opt/anaconda3/envs/handle_queue/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/context.py", line 284, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/Users/main_user/opt/anaconda3/envs/handle_queue/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 32, in __init__
    super().__init__(process_obj)
  File "/Users/main_user/opt/anaconda3/envs/handle_queue/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/Users/main_user/opt/anaconda3/envs/handle_queue/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 47, in _launch
    reduction.dump(process_obj, fp)
  File "/Users/main_user/opt/anaconda3/envs/handle_queue/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref' object
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: The process target "self.store_value" is an object-bound method. This means the Storage object must be pickled as well. I guess that the contained Manager instance can't be pickled.

Comment: @MichaelButscher should I define a customized manager to register the `Storage`class with the manager class?

Comment: I would try to not store the manager in the Storage object. After the "orderbooks" dictionary was created, it isn't needed any longer (and shouldn't be used by the child processes anyway, I think).

Comment: Michael is correct that a `multiprocessing.Manager` cannot be sent to a child process, so the fact that you keep a reference `self.manager` is what the error comes from. If you need access to the `manager` instance to create new proxies from a child process, you should follow the steps to ["connect to a remote manager"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager.connect) inside the child process. If you want to bind that manager to a `Storage` instance, you'll probably have to customize the pickle behavior (with `__getstate__` etc..)

Comment: @MichaelButscher thank you. So, should I define the Manager().dict() in the main process and giving it to the object at the initialization? Would this work?

Comment: @Aaron The previous comment is also for you - if you have any opinion

Comment: @apt45 yes that is a more common pattern. the main process "owns" the manager, and instances created by that manager are what get passed around. I would not connect children to the manager unless you cannot preallocate your shared objects in the main process, and simply pass them to the child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Aaron's posted comment:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

class Storage():
    def __init__(self, orderbooks):
        self.orderbooks = orderbooks

    def store_value(self, el):
        self.orderbooks[el[0]] = el[1]

    def write(self, el: list):
        p = Process(target=self.store_value, args=(el,))
        p.start()
        # Ensure we do not return until store_value has
        # completed updating the dictionary:
        p.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    orderbooks = manager.dict()
    book1 = Storage(orderbooks)
    book1.write([0, 1])
    print(orderbooks)
```

Prints:

```None
{0: 1}
```